# Bootstrap Grid with DIV and borders

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, border

I'm trying to learn some basics of bootstrap. I would like to get a grid like the image below

[image]

What would be the best way to get it?

With `div[class*=col-] {border: 1px solid #ccc}`, I'm getting some double borders :/

Thanks Advance!

**//edit:**
**CSS:**

```
.next .row {
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

.next .row [class*="col-"] {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 50px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.next .row [class*="col-"]:last-child  {
  border-left:0;
  border-right:0;
  border-bottom:0;
  height:100%;
}

.next .row [class*="col-md"]:first-child  {
  border:none;
}

@media(min-width:992px){
    .next .row [class*="col-"]:first-child  {
      border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
      border-right:none;
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container next">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <div class="col-md-7 ">1</div>
            <div class="col-md-5 ">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <div class="col-md-12 ">3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show us what you've got so far.

Comment: the idea would be to mark some elements with some classes, then applying not just ``border: 1px solid``, but for some of them - only ``border-top, -right and -bottom`` for others - ``top, left and bottom``, and using ``:nth-child`` and ``:first and -last child`` controll all of that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
div[class*=col-] {border-right: 1px solid #ccc; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;}
div[class*=col-]:first-child {border-left: 1px solid #ccc; border-top:1px solid #ccc;}
```